# CountdownTimer is not Running in Runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable, countdowntimer, java-threads

Hello Developers This question may seem foolish to some readers and it may have answered before but I have seen many answers on this forum regarding my issue but I could not understand single one of them. So please be kind and answer my question if you could.

The thing is I am trying to develop something like a game and trying to add computer or AI player against a human player.

For that I added a `CountdownTimer` in `OnCreate` method and it worked fine only once as OnCreate executes only once.  But when I tried to add a while loop inside a runnable and inside that while loop I added the same CountdownTimer but it started giving me errors.

```
if(player2_name.equals("Computer")) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (player2_name.equals("Computer")) {
                  CountDownTimer computer_player;
                   ct = 5;
                   firstplayer_game_button.setClickable(false);
                   computer_player = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                       @Override
                       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                           ct = ct - 1;
                    //       timer_counter.setText("" + ct);
                           if (ct == 1) {
                               firstplayer_game_button.setClickable(true);
                           }
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onFinish() {
                        //   secondplayer_game_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_player_2);
                        //   firstplayer_game_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_player_1);
                        //   firstplayer_game_button.setClickable(true);
                           if (player2_name.equals("Computer")) {

                               secondplayer_game_button.setClickable(false);

                           } else {
                               secondplayer_game_button.setClickable(true);
                           }
                           if (checker != 1) {
                               Click_Condition_checker(2);
                           }
                       }
                   };
                   computer_player.start();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread mythread = new Thread(r);
        mythread.start();
```

I know that a Runnable cannot interact with UI directly and for that we need handlers that is why I commented all the UI interfaces. But still no luck. And unfortunately I am not able to identify the errors. If Someone can help then it would be very kind for a foolish developer like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `Runnable` to make a `CountDownTimer` works. It's because `CountDownTimer` can directly interact with the UI if the code running inside the `Activity`.

Second, you should not use while loop inside your code. Especially for the following code:

```
while (player2_name.equals("Computer")) {
   CountDownTimer computer_player;
   ...
   computer_player = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {}
   ...
}
```

which means you're creating new object until you exhausted all the device memory or until player2_name is not `"Computer"`.

You should using a boolean flag instead.

I think what you need is can be achieved by restarting the `CountDownTimer` with something like this:

```
// use a more readable variable name instead of computer_player
final CountDownTimer cdtPlayer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
   @Override
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     // do something
   }

   @Override
   public void onFinish() {
     // do something

     // restart to do all again
     cdtPlayer.start();
   }
};

cdtPlayer.start();
```

---

Regarding your following statement:

> If Someone can help then it would be very kind for a foolish developer like me.

Everybody is a foolish when starting to learn something. Don't be too hard with yourself ;)

Comment: Thanks  a lot this is a big help for me . . .Thanks for your kind comments as well.

Comment: @ZubairRasheed: Great it help you! You're very welcome. Well, I once thinking I'm a foolish developer too. Until someone teach me to change my perspective and to learn by hardworking. I partly remember a wise quote from a book, something like: `If somebody 10 times smarter than you, it means that you need to learn 10 times more to be smarter.` You got what I meant :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your goal but your while loop seems troublesome. A while testing a string and not changing its value, it's going to run over and over (and by then create that many CountdownTimer which I don't think was your intent)